with MUI DataGrid (pro) and client-side sorting, how can I get the current order of rows?
MUI's DataGrid has a great API around sorting.
We would like to get the current order of the rows in the table when using client sorting mode.
Is there a way to read the current rows, in order from the DataGrid?
The use case for us is that when the user clicks on a row, it navigates to a details view of that row with the option to navigate back and forth to the details of the previous and next row. We would like to leverage the built-in sorting.
We could use server mode, but then we are the ones who need to deal with sorting. And since some of data is not flat, we would have to rewrite the concepts of value getter for the column that DataGrid already has.
